# aws-sdk : DynamoDB : Fetch list of all tables

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

I am using aws-sdk for nodejs in a project, and not finding any way to fetch all tables from an endpoint, in other words I am looking forward for equivalent of following command in SDK.

```
aws dynamodb list-tables --endpoint-url <ENDPOINT_URL>
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Regards.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks friends, I found the solution as

```
 const AWS = require("aws-sdk");
 var dynamodb = new AWS.DynamoDB();
 var param = {}
    dynamodb.listTables(param, function (err, data) {
        if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
        else     console.log(data);           // successful response
      });
```

Comment: As pagination is not handled, not all the table names are read.

Answer (score 8):

If you have more than 100 tables, then you also need to be aware of pagination. You can use this example for Node.js:

```js
const readAllTables = async() => {
  const AWS = require("aws-sdk");
  var dynamodb = new AWS.DynamoDB();

  var params = {};
  var tables = [];

  while(true) {
    var response = await dynamodb.listTables(params).promise();
    tables = tables.concat(response.TableNames);

    if (undefined === response.LastEvaluatedTableName) {
      break;
    } else {
      params.ExclusiveStartTableName = response.LastEvaluatedTableName;
    }
  }

  return tables;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at:

`listTables(params = {}, callback)`

"Returns an array of table names associated with the current account and endpoint."

Here: [AWS SDK for JavaScript - DynamoDB](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB.html)

Answer (score 1):

here is an example, it will return an array of table names

```js
// Imports
const AWS = require('aws-sdk')

AWS.config.update({ region: 'eu-west-3' });

// Declare local variables
const dynamo = new AWS.DynamoDB();

function getDynamoTables() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        dynamo.listTables({} , (err, data) => {
            if(err) reject(err);
            else resolve(data);
        })
    })
}

module.exports = {
    getDynamoTables
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an improved TypeScript implementation based on @JaXt0r's code. Like his answer this will handle the pagination.

```
import {DynamoDB} from "@aws-sdk/client-dynamodb";
const readAllTables = async (client: DynamoDB): Promise<string[]> => {
    const params: ListTablesCommandInput = {};
    let tableNames: string[] = [];
    while (true) {
        const response = await client.listTables(params);
        tableNames = tableNames.concat(response.TableNames);

        if (!response.LastEvaluatedTableName) {
            break;
        }

        params.ExclusiveStartTableName = response.LastEvaluatedTableName;
    }

    return tableNames;
}
```

Usage:

```
const client = new DynamoDB();
console.log(await readAllTables(client))
```

Answer (score 0):

In my project for a [dynamodb-dashboard](https://github.com/kritish-dhaubanjar/dynamodb-dashboard), this was my approach for listing all tables:

```js
const AWS = require("aws-sdk");
const dynamodb = new AWS.DynamoDB();

async function all() {
    const tables = [];
    const params = {};

    do {
      const response = await dynamodb.listTables(params);
      tables.push(...response.TableNames);
      params.LastEvaluatedTableName = response.ExclusiveStartTableName;
    } while (params.LastEvaluatedTableName);

    return tables;
}
```